# user A session gets user B session laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

The user A logged in with the role "admin". User B logged in as role "LimitedUser" on same web portal.
User A changes the permissions for use B. Both of them are on same page, i.e "Attach Permission to Role Page". User A disallows user B to access the page, and when User A submits the form, User B refreshes their page and gets the session of User A. This happens only if User A submits the form and User B redirects the page at the same time.

Laravel Version: 5.6
Entrust for Role Management
Session: File Based

Here's the code.

```
function updatePermissions(Request $request)
{
    if (!hasRole('SuperAdmin') && !userCan('attach_permissions')) {
        abort('404');
    }

    $roleId = $request->input('role_id');
    $permIds = $request->input('perm');
    $role = Role::where('id', '=', $roleId)->first();
    if (!$role) {
        abort('404');
    }
    if ($permIds == null) {
        $role = Role::findOrFail($roleId);
        $role_permissions = $role->perms()->get();
        //print_r($role_permissions);exit;
        $rolePermIds = array();
        foreach ($role_permissions as $permission) {
            $rolePermIds[] = $permission->id;
        }
        $role->perms()->detach($rolePermIds);
    } else {
        /*$role->perms()->sync(array_keys($permIds));*/
        $permissions_new = (array_keys($permIds));
        RolePermission::where('role_id', '=', $roleId)->forceDelete();
        foreach ($permissions_new as $item) {
            $r = new RolePermission();
            $r->role_id = $role->id;
            $r->permission_id = $item;
            $r->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter framework but I think the structure is the same as Laravel. So here is how it does the work like what you need. First, in every controller you need to fetch the user access data from the database and set it into session so that your session will be able to fetch the new data. Second, do a validation to validate the access for the page. These fetching and validating data should be done in the `__construct()`

Comment: You aren't testing both users with the same browser, are you?

Comment: @aynber. I am using firefox for one user and chrome for second user

Comment: @ceejayoz. I've update the question with code.

Comment: Did you check same auth with Cookie-based?

Comment: Here where is SESSION related code?

Comment: I guess the problem here is with the session file. which when read and written at the same time, this issue occurs. But I'm not sure if this is the case or it's laravel

Comment: Please try with session cookie... If you get same error, You should check your auth function...

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar. yes, I tried the cookie too. but the issue persists. I am using default (Auth) - LoginController provided by laravel.

Comment: Whoops.... Can you share your controller and middleware?

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar. here's the URL for code http://lalaland.pk/code.txt

Comment: Are you logging in with 2 users in the same browser at the same time and expecting them to have different sessions?

Comment: @Bryan. no. both of them are opened in two different browsers.
After doing some research I found out that this is called "race condition". But I can't find solution so far. On concurrent request on same URL, the session sort of swaps between users

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to solve this, one of them is to do Middleware in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#defining-middleware

Another way, creating `Policies` and `Gates`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#gates

In the your case, `middleware` can solve.

Comment: I'm using default auth middleware already. but it's still creating the issue

Comment: So... now you have to use policies, by the way you said parace a blog, you can create a mini acl

Comment: I am already using Entrust for this purpose. The problem is with someone's session being assigned to another user on concurrent requests

Comment: hm, you using token?

Comment: Using Laravel Auth with Entrust